# PHP/SQL errors that i cant seem to find

Tags: php, sql

When executed, it always states that "the parking bay is not available at this time", even though the database given says otherwise. what am I doing wrong? There possibly may be other errors, but i cant seem to get past this one.

```
$db = connect();
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    if(isWeekend($bookingDate)){
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT bayid FROM parkbay p WHERE p.bayid=:bayID AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM parkbay p WHERE p.bayid=:bayID AND(:parktime BETWEEN avail_wend_start AND avail_wend_end) AND (:parktime+:duration BETWEEN avail_wend_start AND avail_wend_end))');
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT bayid FROM parkbay p WHERE p.bayid=:bayID AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM parkbay p WHERE p.bayid=:bayID AND(:parktime BETWEEN avail_wk_start AND avail_wk_end) AND (:parktime+:duration BETWEEN avail_wk_start AND avail_wk_end))');
    }
    $stmt->bindValue(':bayID', $bayID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':parktime', $bookingHour, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':duration', $duration, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    if ( !empty($result) ) {             
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM booking b JOIN parkbay p ON (p.bayid=b.bayid) WHERE b.bayid=:bayID2 AND b.bookingdate=:bookingDate2 AND (:parktime2 BETWEEN b.bookinghour AND b.bookinghour + b.duration) AND (:parktime2 + :duration2 BETWEEN b.bookinghour AND b.bookinghour + b.duration)" );
        $stmt2->bindValue(':bayID2', $bayID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt2->bindValue(':bookingDate2', $bookingDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->bindValue(':parktime2', $bookingHour, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt2->bindValue(':duration2', $duration, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $result = $stmt2->fetchAll();
        $stmt2->closeCursor();
        if ( empty($result) ) {                 
            $stmt3 = $db->prepare("SELECT c.name, t.width, t.height, t.length FROM cartype t JOIN car c ON (c.make = t.make AND c.model = t.model) WHERE c.name=:carname AND EXISTS (
SELECT p.site, p.length, p.width, p.height FROM parkbay p WHERE p.bayid=:bayID3 AND t.width<=p.width AND t.length<=p.length AND t.height<=p.height)");
            $stmt3->bindValue(':bayID3', $bayID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt3->bindValue(':carname', $car, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt3->execute();
            $result = $stmt3->fetch();
            $stmt3->closeCursor();
            if ( !empty($result) ) { 
                $stmt4 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO booking (bookingid, bayid, bookingdate, bookinghour, duration, memberno, car) VAlUES (DEFAULT, :bayIDBooking, :bookingDateBooking, :bookingHourBooking, :durationBooking, :memberNoBooking, :carBooking) RETURNING bookingid');
                $stmt4->bindValue(':bayIDBooking',$bayID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt4->bindValue(':bookingDateBooking',$bookingDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt4->bindValue(':bookingHourBooking',$bookingHour,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt4->bindValue(':durationBooking',$duration,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt4->bindValue(':memberNoBooking',$memberNo,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt4->bindValue(':carBooking',$car,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt4->execute();
                $bookingID = $stmt4->fetchColumn();
                $stmt4->closeCursor();
                if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
                    $db->commit();
                    $stmt5 = $db->prepare('SELECT b.*, (p.hourly_rate * b.duration) as cost FROM booking b JOIN member m ON (b.memberno = m.memberno) JOIN membershipplan p ON (m.plan = p.title) WHERE b.bookingid=:bookingID');
            $stmt5->bindValue(':bookingID',$bookingID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt5->execute();
                    if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
                        $results = $stmt5->fetch();
                        $stmt5->closeCursor();
                        $results['status']='success';
                        return $results;
                    }else{ //STMT 5 - confirm Booking Insert and Cost - Fail
                        $db->rollback();
                        $results['status']=' Error making booking and getting cost. Check that membership plan is set.';
                        return $results;
                    }
                }else{ //STMT 4 - Insert Booking Data - Fail
                    $db->rollback();
                    $results['status']='Error making booking.';
                    return $results;
                }
            } else { //STMT 3 - Check Car Dimensions - Fail
                $db->rollback();
                $results['status']='Your car is too big for this parking bay.';
                return $results;
            }                
        } else { //STMT 2 - Check Existing Bookings - Fail
            $db->rollback();
            $results['status']='A booking already exists at this time.';
            return $results;
        }                 
    } else { //STMT 1 - Check Parking Availability - Fail
        $db->rollback();
        $results['status']='This parking bay is not available at this time.';
        return $results;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error submitting query to databse: " . $e->getMessage();
;
}
}
```

where:

```
function isWeekend($bookingDate) {
return (date('N', strtotime($bookingDate)) >= 6);
```

Comment: your code is so long, you should remove all the non-relevant part, if you want to get some help. And if you want your code to be maintainable, you should create several functions to do what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

**Edit for explanation of process**

Don't be afraid of down-votes;  They aren't personal.  They are there because viewers don't see evidence of having tried to solve the problem yourself.

As you are a new SO user, here are some troubleshooting tips:

As a basic rule, to figure out where the error is, break it down to it's basic pieces.  In your case, look at what drives that specific error.  In this case it is because of this line `if ( !empty($result) )`.  You instructed it to print that message if this *isn't* the case;  it's coming from your `else` statement.  This means that `$result` is empty.  If it's not empty, you need to figure out why.

In this particular instance it appears that you don't appear to be doing any kind of row count in your query, so by default, it will show as empty.

You can get a row count by doing something like this (using your code example):

```
$row_count = $result->rowCount();
```

From the documentation here:  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php:

> use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.